# How do I show a loading placeholder for an image when using the NgOptimizedImage directive?

Tags: angular

I've recently changed all my images to use the `NgOptimizedImage` directive for loading performance, however now due to the lazy loading there's sometimes a noticeable delay on swiper elements when bring images that haven't loaded into the viewport.

To improve this I'm trying to implement a loading placeholder for all my images in my Angular app, so that while fetching an image (onload) a skeleton-text element is shown in its place.

I  came across [this article](https://dev.to/krivanek06/angular-default-image-placeholder-3dfc) which shows how to use a directive to add a placeholder image; however I'm unsure how I'd implement this given the optimised image directive uses the native element's events.

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried using the directive from https://dev.to/krivanek06/angular-default-image-placeholder-3dfc in combination with the NgOptimizedImage directive however it has no effect / changes are ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular team [just landed](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f5c520b836c4545c7043649f28b3a0369c168747) a change to the NgOptimizedImage directive to allow a placeholder.

The feature is available the latest prerelease (17.2.0-next.1). The final 17.2 minor is expected for Feb 15th.

Comment: This is why I love Angular! Thanks Matthieu for making me aware of this